# Xamarin, how can i access a specific column property in sqlite so i can add the values?

Tags: sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I know how to read or show all data inserted in the database but I don't know how to query a specific data.  In the my database is in Post.cs it will store date/time and get 2 datas from user.
so like this: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRCJj.png)

```
Column1(ID), Column2(Date), (column3(rain1), column4(rain2).
1              12/13/2019         21               22
2              12/16/2019         21               22
3              12/16/2019         11               12
```

I want to do: if (rain1 && rain2) have the same date.  I would like to add 2data from rain1 which is 21+11 and save the total to rain1total=32 then rain2total would be 34.  I don't know where to start

here is Post.cs

```
namespace listtoPDF.Model
{
//Post table, user posting drainvolume
//this is the source of Binding
public class Post: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private double? rain1Vol;
    private double? rain2Vol;
    //from settingspage to show up in history
    string rain1lbl = Settings.Drain1LocationSettings;
    string rain2lbl = Settings.Drain2LocationSettings;      

    //ID primary key that we will autoincrement
    //These are columns ID, drain1 to 8 so 9 columns
    //These are binding source for Historypage
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public static bool showLabel { get; set; }  //public class model

    public string rain1Lbl
    {
        get => rain1lbl;
        set => rain1lbl= Settings.Drain1LocationSettings;    
    }

    public string rain2Lbl
    {
        get => rain2lbl;
        set => rain2lbl= Settings.Drain2LocationSettings;    
    }

    public string CDateTime { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(3)]
    public double? rain1vol
    {
        get { return rain1Vol; }
        set
        {
            rain1Vol = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("rain1vol");
        }
    }
    [MaxLength(3)]
    public double? rain2vol
    {
        get { return rain2Vol; }
        set
        {
            rain2Vol = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("rain2vol");
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    void RaisePropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }

    }
}
}
```

here is the main that will list data entered with date

```
namespace listtoPDF
{
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    List<Post> posts;


    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(App.DatabaseLocation);
        conn.CreateTable<Post>();
        posts = conn.Table<Post>().ToList();
        postListView.ItemsSource = posts;     
        conn.Close();
            //right click quickwatch

    }
    void addbuttonHandle_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        Navigation.PushModalAsync(new AddRainsPage());

    }

    private void GetValues()
    {
        //Initiate SQLite connection
        //Create table with class
        //Get the values in table
        //close the line
        SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(App.DatabaseLocation);
        conn.CreateTable<Post>();
        posts = conn.Table<Post>().ToList();
        conn.Close();
    }       
}
```

Here is the page where i need query the add a certain column so i can add the data associated to it.  So far it's connecting to the sqlite.

```
namespace listtoPDF
{
public partial class selecteddataPage : ContentPage
{
    List<Post> posts;

    public selecteddataPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void GetValues()
    {
        //Initiate SQLite connection
        //Create table with class
        //Get the values in table
        //close the line
        SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(App.DatabaseLocation);
        conn.CreateTable<Post>();
        posts = conn.Table<Post>().ToList();

        **if (Post.rain1 values have the same date )
          {
             totalrain1= then add data that have same date         
          }
         if (Post.rain2 values have the same date )
          {
             totalrain1= then add data that have same date         
          }**

        conn.Close();

    }
}
}
```

Comment: read up on using Group By and aggregate queries in SQLite.  And don't store DateTime values as strings, SQLite has native support for DateTime

Comment: alternatively you could do it with a LINQ query after you get the data from the db

Comment: you are right, LINQ might be a better solution... from what I'm reading and on tutorials on LINQ...

Comment: @chemobrain For query of sqlite, you could refer to the MS docs. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/data-cloud/data-access/using-sqlite-orm#selecting-an-object-using-linq